# Check if fields generated by *ngFor are valid with required flag

Tags: html, angular, validation, ngfor

i have this *ngFor for some input fields,

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let qp of myQuoted.quoteQuantityPrice; let index = i;">
            <td>
                <input #ng_price[i]="ngModel" class="number" type="number" pattern="[1-9]*" [(ngModel)]="qp.price" required>
            </td>
        </ng-container>
```

and I want this button to be disables if any of the #ng_price fields doesn't follow the regex pattern doesn't have any data in it

for objects that have only one input field ever I have the button disabled like this:

```html
 <button [disabled]= "ng_supplier.invalid || ng_inventory.invalid || ng_leadWeeks.invalid || ng_multOrderQty.invalid || ng_minOrderQty.invalid" (click)="Save()">Save</button>
```

I want to add `ng_price.invalid` to that list of validators
I tried adding `ng_price.invalid` in the disabled block but as I expected it doesn't really work like that and building the project ends up failing because `ng_price.invalid` does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

**html**

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let qp of myQuoted.quoteQuantityPrice; let index = i;">
    <td>
    <form [formGroup]="formArr[i]">
        <input formControlName="app_price" class="number" type="number">
      </form>
    </td>
 </ng-container>
```

...

```
<button [disabled]= "(formArr[i].get('app_price').touched && formArr[i].get('app_price').invalid) || ng_supplier.invalid || ng_inventory.invalid || ng_leadWeeks.invalid || ng_multOrderQty.invalid || ng_minOrderQty.invalid" (click)="Save()">Save</button>
```

**ts**

```
    formArr: any[] = [];
    pricePattern: any = "[1-9]*" ;
```

...

```
  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
  ) {
        for (let j of this.myQuoted.quoteQuantityPrice) {
          this.formArr.push(
            this.fb.group({
              app_price: ["", [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.pricePattern)]],
            })
          );
        }
   }
```

...